# Python string formatting using the locals() dictionary - list vs generator

Tags: python, scope, string-formatting

When I need to print variables, I tend to be lazy and use `"{someVariable}".format( **locals() )` a lot. For example:

```
x = 10
[ "{x} {i}".format( **locals() ) for i in xrange(3) ]
```

Out:

```
['10 0', '10 1', '10 2']
```

But now if I use a generator instead:

```
x = 10
for y in ( "{x} {i}".format( **locals() ) for i in xrange(3) ) :
    print y
```

Out:

```
KeyError: 'x'
```

Oh no! What happened?

Comment: My answer on the dupe explains why; generators are run in a separate scope. In Python 2.7 list comprehensions don't, in Python 3 they too are run in a separate scope.

Comment: In other words, `x` is not a local in a generator expression, it is instead either a closure or a global.